# Convert android project to java project

Tags: java, android, jar, apk

I've just finished developing an application for android. I want to have a desktop version that is based on java, too.

I have to convert all layouts to swing and what other conflicts I may face, god knows.

Is there a tool for converting android apps to jar standalone? What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: No tool that I know of or can ever imagine. Your best bet is to design and code with high cohesion, low coupling, and good MVC separation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no tool to do this, as Android and Normal Java apps are very different.

The best you could do is move the non platform specific code into a library project, and reference it from both the Java and Android applications. So all code that doesn't use any import with android in it should be movable into the library, while all your swing/android specific code will go into the referencing projects.